# How to correct a mistake made on EEA FP already submitted application

Tags: uk-visa

I made a mistake on the application form. I forgot to write my husband's National Insurance number which he has never used to work in the UK. He only applied for it earlier this year. I have already submitted the form, signed the declaration page and printed out the application form.

Please what shall I do? Should I leave it as it is or correct it with an ink?  I have my biometric tomorrow?
Please I need advise?

Answer (score 1):

You can write it in, but if you are uncertain about doing that, you can also just leave it off.  It is not a critical piece of information; I would not worry too much about it.